# Is it possible to set the height of div to a set distance from the bottom of fixed position footer?

Tags: jquery, css, height

Lord, I'm not even sure how to phrase the title for this one.

I've included an image of what I'm trying to accomplish below.
http://www.wideeyedcommunications.com/images/positioning-sample.png

I have a footer set to the bottom of the screen. A containing div is overlapping that footer. I need that containing div's height to be a set distance from the bottom of the screen irrespective of the resolution of the screen or the quantity of the content in the containing div.

So, the green footer (squiggle) is always locked to the bottom of the screen, and the bottom of the brown div is within, let's say 20 pixels of the bottom of the screen no matter how much or little content is within that div.

So if I have 1 line of text and no scrollbars, then it's height is `viewport - 20px`. And if I have 1000 lines of text and scrollbars the height is still `viewport - 20 px`.

I'd guess that jquery could do it with something like:

```
$(".container").height(function(){
  $(window).height-20;
});
```

But is it possible to accomplish this without using javascript?

Edit: Here's some of the code.

```
<body>
  <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <div id="grass">&nbsp;</div>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        Navbar, content, etc goes here
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the existing css

```
#grass {
  background: url("../images/bg_grass.jpg") repeat-x scroll center bottom;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -10;
}
#container {
  margin: 35px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
#content {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFF8ED;
  border: 2px solid #764C29;
  border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've just uploaded a demo site to http://jsfiddle.net/Fireflight/HQvay/

Comment: Can we see some of the code or a demo site?

Comment: I've added a link above to a demo site.

Comment: Adding `position: absolute; min-height: 100%;` to `#content` creates the effect I'm looking for on larger screens, but breaks the layout on small screens. The footer slides under the content in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add a `margin-bottom` to your container, and then set it's height with jQuery:

CSS:

```
.container { margin: 20px auto }
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
      $('.container').css('height', $(window).height() - 40);
}).resize();
```

Note: If your container has padding and/or borders, you'll have to include those in your calculations.

Comment: This is almost it. When the screen is shrunk down too small, the existing content is hidden as I'm using overflow:hidden. I've just uploaded a better example to http://jsfiddle.net/Fireflight/HQvay/1/

Comment: This ended up working as `$(window).resize(function(){var bodyheight = $('body').height(); $('#content').css('min-height', bodyheight+'px');}).resize();
`

Answer (score 1):

```
.container
{position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;}
```

Have you tried that one?
(could use fixed but that all depends on the code.  could we have more of the HTML markup?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you just need to add a `margin-bottom: 20px` style to your div and it will always stay at least 20px from the bottom of the page.

Comment: I thought that too, but then what if the content only has one line of text? Then the page will float above the footer.

Comment: Perhaps set a min height for your div? That way it can expand with more content, but will always have a specific height for the page.

Comment: I don't believe you can set height: 100% - @Joseph Silber's answer is probably going to be the easiest path.

Comment: Actually this can be done in pure css it's just we don't have enough code. :P  At the very least we could add a 100% width and height wrapper and set the bottom property.